How can I fix a gap left after installing a new deadbolt?
I replaced the deadbolt in the door with a new one and now there's a small gap on one side of the deadbolt. How do I fix this?


Do you have the same gap on the right side of the bolt?

Please show a photo that isn't so close up. Also tell us more about the situation, such as bore diameter and hardware model.

Door latches and deadbolts can have different backsets. (distance from the edge of the door to the center of the hole)
You need to consult the instructions for your new deadbolt and adjust it for a longer backset.  That will move the body of the unit to cover the entire hole.
If the new deadbolt is not adjustable, you will need to return it and purchase a unit with the correct backset.

Yup. Remove the new lock and measure the distance from the edge of the door to the center-line of the hole, it will be either 2 3/8" or 2 3/4" (this is the "backset"). The latch for the new lock should be adjustable for either. It looks like you have a 2 3/8" latch on a 2 3/4" backset hole.

99.9% sure this answer is correct, but if the backset is optimum, maybe you’ll be able to shift the knob a tiny bit over. Don’t push it too much, though, as these locks are sensitive to binding from misalignment. If nothing else works, use wood filler.

In regular "Kwikset"-style key-lock deadbolts there is a collar that projects off the back of the outside part of the lock to fit inside the door's hole, so the outside part cannot be slid sideways. It seems that this keypad lock is either missing the collar or doesn't have it. Check for it when you reassemble or replace the keypad lock.

If not possible to move or exchange the deadbolt, you can cut a small piece of wood to match the gap.
Remove the deadbolt, and with a 1/2 or 3/4 thick piece of wood, cut it to match the hole/gap.
With small screws and glue, attach it so it will cover the gap.
Sand smooth and paint to match.

Usual pro solution is a "decorative" brass mending plate.

This isn't true. That looks like a standard door bore. There's no need for band-aid fixes here.

@isherwood: Hard to be sure without seeing more of the door, or seeing measurements. Simply adjusting the back set may indeed be enough, or the bore may be of a size where a supporting ring is needed, or it may be misplaced entirely. I've dealt with all of the above.
